# How to integrate RTPS live stream link to Yolo Algorithm

Tags: yolo

I am using this command

```
!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smZRzehsXHA -i 0
```

into Google Colab but i am getting

```
Total BFLOPS 65.864 
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 18.91 MB 
Loading weights from yolov3.weights...
 seen 64 
Done!
video file: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smZRzehsXHA
 Video-stream stopped! 
Stream closed.
```